# printing byte values using sprintf using decimal and hexa decimal formats

Tags: arrays, c, hex, printf

I have following program written in C

```
unsigned char data[32];
size_t data_len = sizeof(data);
for (size_t i = 0; i < data_len; ++i)
{
   data[i] = i;
}

unsigned char vrkbuffer[data_len * 2 + 1];
unsigned char vrkbufferonebytehex[data_len * 2 + 1];
unsigned char vrkbuffertwobytehex[data_len * 2 + 1];
for (size_t i = 0; i < data_len; ++i)
{
    sprintf(&vrkbuffer[i], "%d", data[i]);
    sprintf(&vrkbufferonebytehex[i], "%x", data[i]);
    sprintf(&vrkbuffertwobytehex[i * 2], "%02X", data[i]);

}
printf("Version 1 \n");
printf("vrk buffer %s\n", vrkbuffer);
printf("vrk buffer %s\n", vrkbufferonebytehex);
printf("vrk buffer %s\n", vrkbuffertwobytehex);
```

output:

```
    Version 1 
vrk buffer 012345678911111111112222222222331
vrk buffer 0123456789abcdef1111111111111111f
vrk buffer 000102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F101112131415161718191A1B1C1D1E1F
```

To my understanding one byte can store value from 0 to 255.

My questions are

1. Why when I am printing value as integer values are not showing correctly ?
2. Why hexa decimal values are shown differently for %x and %02x?

Request the concept behind why we are seeing the output shown below?

Comment: `sprintf(&vrkbufferonebytehex[i], "%x", data[i]);`???  What makes you think `%x` will only produce one byte of output?

Comment: @Andrew Henle my understanding is that 0 to 32 values fit in one byte so %x will produce one byte. Please correct if I am wrong. Thanks

Comment: Values 0 to 255 fit in one byte. But the question is how many chars (and each char use 1 byte in representation `&vrkbufferonebytehex[i]`) you need to print them in a humanly understandable way. In base 10, for example, only values 0 to 9 need only 1 byte in the string that represent them. In hexadecimal, only values 0 to 15 need only 1 byte.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, the length of the array should be obtained from

```
size_t data_len = sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0]);
```

Although here just `sizeof(data);` works because each element is size `1`.

---

> **Why when I am printing value as integer values are not showing correctly?**

Consider the first `sprintf`. The first 10 iterations are in no doubt and generate a string

```
"0123456789"
```

The next iteration for `10` makes the string like this

```
"012345678910"
```

The following iterations make the string like this

```
"0123456789111"                     // 11
"01234567891112"                    // 12
"012345678911113"                   // 13
. . .
"012345678911111111119"             // 19
"0123456789111111111120"            // 20
. . .
"0123456789111111111122222222229"   // 29
"01234567891111111111222222222230"  // 30
"012345678911111111112222222222331" // 31
```

Each time (except the last) you are overwriting the second digit generated by the previous iteration.

---

> **Why hexa decimal values are shown differently for `%x` and `%02x`?**

Because of the field width specifier. For values less than `16` they respectively generate (say for `15`)

```
F
0F
```

the second is zero-padded to width 2.

Comment: Thanks for response. I have to generate bytes rather than char values. But my question is why we are seeing the output shown in above code.

Comment: @venkysmarty you are reading beyond the end the array which results in _undefined behaviour_ (google that term) which in your case probably boils down to reading and displaying whatever garbage is stored in memory after the arrays.

Comment: @venkysmarty because `%d` will output in decimal. Outputting say `10` gives a string like `"10"` with a NUL terminator.

Comment: @WeatherVane why second digit is overwriting in each iteration. Thanks for your guidance

Comment: Because you told it to advance the writing position by **1** in each loop, with `&vrkbuffer[i]`.